# Which font formats does iOS support?

Tags: ios, fonts

I'd like to know which font formats iOS supports. I already know that iOS supports the TTF format. Does it support any others—for example, PFM or PMB?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of iOS 7, both TTF and OTF font formats are supported. You can distribute these fonts in your apps, or through configuration profiles (to make them available system wide).

Comment: Others have reported that OTF works too, and probably others. Ref:http://www.freetimestudios.com/2010/09/13/custom-fonts-on-the-ipad-and-ios-4/#comment-77340205

Comment: Any updates on this?  Possible supporting some of the native OS X fonts stored in `.dfont` format?

Comment: So Apple's developer site now documents that OTF and TTF fonts are now supported (I've updated the answer to reflect this). Unfortunately that's as far as official support goes. For other formats your mileage will vary.

Comment: Any chance you have the link lying around ? Can't seem to find anything on the official docs (WOFF/WOFF2 works in Safari as of iOS 10 and so do custom fonts in such formats but there's no info)

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 10, both WOFF and WOFF2 formats are supported. Though there's no info about it

Answer (score 4):

The official documentation on this is spotty to say the least. In the article [Adding a Custom Font to Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app), Apple states that can use `True Type Font (.ttf) and Open Type Font (.otf) files`.

In related Apple documentation for setting up a [configuration profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)  on iOS, Apple states that you can use

> [a] font file in TrueType (.ttf) or OpenType (.otf) format. Collection formats (.ttc or .otc) are not supported.

Again only True Type Fonts and Open Type Fonts are official supported. Although this document is not directly related to app development. It is further evidence for official support for fonts only extending to `.ttf` and `.otf`.

I couldn't find any official documentation for WOFF or WOFF2 support outside of Safari.