# ionic 2 - Font not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, css, fonts, ionic2

I'm trying to create an app (ionic 2) with a custom font, Quicksand.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
src
|
|-app
|   |
|   -app
|   |   |
|   |   -app.scss
|   |
|   -pages
|   |
|   -assets
|   |     |
|   |     -img
|   |     |
|   |     -fonts
|   |     |    |
|   |     |    -Quicksand-Bold.ttf
```

In my `app.scss` I have the following code to make the font available in all my pages:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quicksand-Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Quicksand-Bold'), local('Quicksand-Bold'), url("../assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf") format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Quicksand-Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Quicksand-Bold'), local('Quicksand-Bold'), url("../assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf") format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Then I can reference it anywhere using `font-family: Quicksand-Bold`.

This works perfectly fine on Android and in the browser, but it fails to load on iOS.

I have already had a problem using:

`background: url('../assets/img/background.jpg')`

which caused my ios app to crash. The workaround I used for this was create a `div` with the image and just position it as the background image.

I have a feeling that the same thing is happening here, when I reference `url("../assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf")` that for some reason iOS is not able to find the path specified.

Comment: Try fontsquirrel: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Throws a `Http Status 500` but what does it do?

Comment: it generates different formats of the font.

Comment: And could that be the issue with iOS? That it doesn't accept the `.ttf` format? (Since it does work both on Android and the browser) Because according to this answer the only fonts supported are `OTF` and `TTF` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277606/which-format-font-ios-supported

Comment: yep. that might solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, viCky 's comment didn't answer my problem but did send me up the right path.

In my question, you can see that I reference a `.ttf` file and try to format it as `woff2`. But since only `otf` and `ttf` fonts are supported in iOS, using a `.woff2` format will break the fonts. The correct format for a `.ttf` file is `TrueType`.

So changing to:

```
src: local('Quicksand-Bold'), local('Quicksand-Bold'), url("../assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
```

Instead of

```
src: local('Quicksand-Bold'), local('Quicksand-Bold'), url("../assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf") format('woff2');
```

Resolved my issue. Now I can use the fonts in my iOS app.

Comment: Oh, I was just about to add the same as an answer lol Glad to hear that you solved the issue :)

Comment: hahaha.. sometimes just discussion the issue leads you to the right answer.